# Running query on results of a join statement

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to figure out how I can run a query on the results of a join statement I'm doing between two tables.  Basically, I need to get all the entries from More_Info that match the ID of Source_Table between a certain time, and then calculate the difference between Number where PartID = certain things.

Consider the following two tables:

Source_Table

### UniqueID | TimeIn |

```
1    |  051010|
2    |  051545|
3    |  055412|
```

More_Info

### UniqueID | PartID | Number |

```
1    |   500  |   5    |
1    |   505  |   10   |
1    |   510  |   40   |
2    |   500  |   10   |
2    |   505  |   15   |
2    |   510  |   25   |
4    |   500  |   30   |
6    |   505  |   10   |
```

So I know I can run select * from Source_Table left join More_Info using(UniqueID) which will return:

### UniqueID | PartID | Number |

```
1    |   500  |   5    |
1    |   505  |   10   |
1    |   510  |   40   |
2    |   500  |   10   |
2    |   505  |   15   |
2    |   510  |   25   |
```

From this, what I need is to get 'Number' where PartID = 500 or 505, and get the difference, where the results would be like:

### UniqueID | Difference |

```
1    |    5       |
2    |    5       |
```

Having a big of difficulty wrapping my head around this, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Basic SQL statements should not be asked on a programmers-forum. Check this site: https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a couple of subquery eg:

```
select t1.UniqueId, t2.NUmber - t1.Number from  (

    select * from Source_Table left join More_Info using(UniqueID)
) t1  
INNER JOIN  (
    select * from Source_Table left join More_Info using(UniqueID)
) t2 on t1.UniqueID = t2.UniqueID  and t1.PartID = 500 and t2.partId = 505
```